# Regex multiline string to string

Tags: javascript, regex, libreoffice

Trying to match regex on... the following format:

```
1. random string
...random lines of strings
Related Entities
```

So trying to go from "1." to the string "Related Entities" with a variables amount of lines in the middle of it.

Trying another one here...

```
Biography...
...random lines of strings
\n\n\n
```

Trying to select from the string "Biography" until I find 3 blank lines.  Also has some various amount of lines of any characters between the two target strings.

Thanks

Sorry, I've tried:

(\b1.).*(\n.*)(\sR)

(\b1.).*(\n.*){3}  <-- don't know how to make that variable amount though

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And .. how would you do this:  `1 random string` .. `biography` .. `Related Entities` .. `\n\n\n`  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first query you can use:

[`^1\.(?:.*\n)+Related Entities`](https://regex101.com/r/VQIsiv/2)

For the second:

[`^Biography(?:.*\n)+(?:\n){3}`](https://regex101.com/r/VQIsiv/3)

Comment: How do you find any string between paranthesis that contains ateast a year somewhere in itI was thinking something like this: 
    [(].*+\d4}+.*[)]  | [(]+\d4}+.*[)] | [(].*+\d4}+[)]

Comment: You can do: [`(?<=[^0-9])\d{1,4}`](https://regex101.com/r/XVvze8/1). This will work for years with one to 4 digits. For more digits you can use `\d+` instead of `\d{1,4}` in the above regex.

Comment: Thanks Sergio!  How do you capture everything within the paranthesis where the year is found? Ie., "(Some none sense 1984 double think)" <== capture all of that without the quotes.   I'm not having luck with greedy .*

Comment: As long as the parenthesis are not nested, this should work: [`(?<=\()[^(]+\d{1,4}[^)]+`](https://regex101.com/r/XVvze8/2)